# Magento 1.9 : sql script is not running

Tags: php, sql, magento, magento-1.9

Basically what i am trying to do : I want some custom attributes for Customer entity. And to add those fields in db i am executing script.

I tried lots & lots of tweaks , methods but i cant solve SQL script error.
The important thing in it is : **It makes entry in `core_resource` table.**

My script made entry in  `core_resource`.

I made extension according to this **[Alan storm Site](http://alanstorm.com/magento_setup_resources)** .

Any help is highly appreciated.

My extension structure

[image: set up]

Here is my coding part.

**Config file of module**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config>
    <modules>
        <StackExchange2_Customer>
            <version>0.1.0</version>
        </StackExchange2_Customer>
    </modules>
    <global>
        <resources>
            <stackExchange2_customer_setup>
                <setup>
                    <module>StackExchange2_Customer</module>
                    <class>StackExchange2_Customer_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup</class>
<!--                    <class>StackExchange2_Customer_Sql</class>-->
                </setup>
                <!--Mew node-->
                <connection> 
                    <use>core_setup</use>
                </connection>
            </stackExchange2_customer_setup>
            <!--as per sOverflow-->
            <stackExchange2_customer_write>
                    <connection>
                        <use>core_write</use>
                    </connection>
            </stackExchange2_customer_write>
            <stackExchange2_customer_read>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_read</use>
                </connection>
            </stackExchange2_customer_read> 
        </resources>
    </global>   
</config>
```

**Setup.php**

```
<?php

/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
//Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup
class StackExchange2_Customer_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup extends Mage_Core_Model_Resource_Setup{

}
```

**mysql4-install-0.1.0.php**

```
<?php
//echo "in script";die;
$installer = $this;
echo "hi123";
$installer->startSetup();
/* 
 * To change this license header, choose License Headers in Project Properties.
 * To change this template file, choose Tools | Templates
 * and open the template in the editor.
 */
//attr1
$installer->addAttribute('customer','name_of_child', array(
                    'type'      => 'varchar',
                    'label'     => 'Name of child',
                    'input'     => 'text',
                    'position'  => 120,
                    'required'  => false,//or true
                    'is_system' => 0,
));

$attribute1 = Mage::getSingleton('eav/config')->getAttribute('customer', 'name_of_child');

//
$attribute1->setData('used_in_forms', array(
    'adminhtml_customer',
    'checkout_register',
    'customer_account_create',
    'customer_account_edit',
));

//
$attribute1->setData('is_user_defined', 0);

//
$attribute1->save();

Mage::log(__FILE__ . 'Update installed.');
$installer->endSetup();
```

Any help is highly appreciated

**NOTE** : In localhost it gives error : Am I using wrong class or anything missing?

[image]

`( ! ) Fatal error: Call to undefined method StackExchange2_Customer_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup::addAttribute() in D:\xampp\htdocs\mykidscare\app\code\local\StackExchange2\Customer\sql\stackexchange2_customer_setup\mysql4-install-0.1.0.php on line 12`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally i solved it :) .

NOW it works after extending proper class (`Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup`).

```
class StackExchange2_Customer_Model_Resource_Mysql4_Setup extends Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup{ 
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Add the following.

```
 <resources>
        <stackExchange2_customer_setup>
            <setup>
                <module>StackExchange2_Customer</module>
                <class>Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup</class>
            </setup>
            <connection> 
                <use>core_setup</use>
            </connection>
        </stackExchange2_customer_setup>
        <stackExchange2_customer_write>
                <connection>
                    <use>core_write</use>
                </connection>
        </stackExchange2_customer_write>
        <stackExchange2_customer_read>
            <connection>
                <use>core_read</use>
            </connection>
        </stackExchange2_customer_read> 
    </resources>
```

You need to add `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup` class in setup in order to add any attribute.

Comment: So you mean i should use `Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup`  instead of `Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup` But why ?

Comment: You can use that also, as Mage_Customer_Model_Entity_Setup extends Mage_Customer_Model_Resource_Setup, which extends Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup. I usually use Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Setup.

Comment: But why does it work on Localhost only and not on live ? Any idea ?

Comment: is it giving any error OR not running script at all ?

Comment: Please read my question and read **Update** as well. Now it works well ! :) adds columns etc , but some how does not work on live server :( all data is same ! Any idea why ?

Comment: try deleting the setup entry from core_resource table

Comment: did it already bro ! :( still it just makes entry again Without creating fields on LIVE site.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/84427/discussion-between-red-devil-and-pratik-c-joshi).